# View wont update using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I'm having some trouble with getting ScheduledExecutorService to work.

This is the method that i'm calling which ***works*** if I call it without scheduling it.

However, if I call it through an ScheduledExecutorService my screen wont update, it also only runs one time, so I guess there's an exception being thrown, but I dont see an exception on either the server or client.

```
private void getNextRoundFromServer() throws IOException{
    try{
        if(!this.connected) return;
        this.dos.writeByte(2);
        this.dos.flush(); // Send data
        this.grid = (Grid) this.ois.readObject(); //i have checked, i do recieve this object
        setMainPane(render.render(this.grid)); //this renders the view
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how I do my implementation.

```
continuousPlayButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    try{
        Runnable scheduledRound = () -> {
            try {
                getNextRoundFromServer();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(scheduledRound, 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Why isn't my view updating?

## Update

Solution:

As mention by user `tjanu`: I forgot to call `Platform.runLater` on the scheduled task. Which I already did when I called it without scheduling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do UI updates on the JavaFX application thread.

This is what [Platform::runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) is for.

-- edit
As requested, the change needed for this code:

```
private void getNextRoundFromServer() throws IOException{
    try{
        if(!this.connected) return;
        this.dos.writeByte(2);
        this.dos.flush(); // Send data
        this.grid = (Grid) this.ois.readObject(); //i have checked, i do recieve this object
        // This is the needed change
        Platform.runLater(() -> setMainPane(render.render(this.grid))); //this renders the view
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, you're right. Can't believe I missed that, been scratching my head for 4h. I already do it in my other 30 calls... Argghhh. Feel free to update your answer to include the code too.

Answer (score 0):

Not an full answer to your question, but a suggestion.Maybe you could try to override the run() method.

```
Runnable scheduledRound = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            getNextRoundFromServer();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Annotations I.e. `@Override` are not allowed there mydude.

Comment: You seem to have combined an anonymous class with a lambda.

Comment: I know, it either one or the other. So why is your answer a combination of both?

Comment: i use it in refreshing an javafx application streaming a webcam. Unshure if it is a bad practise. though it is an simplification

Comment: You're saying you use this code in an application? Because what you've posted won't compile. Also, the lambda expression _is already_  implementing the single method of the functional interface. So `Runnable r = () -> { /* code */ };` is implementing the `run` method.

Comment: @Slaw that was my point. You cant have both lamdas and override the method. Then the lambda is pointless. I edited his answer *to be compileable*, lets see if he will approve it.

Comment: @Joel Sorry for the confusion, but both my comments were directed at Joa.

Comment: @slaw aah, I had to refresh the page, your first comment wasn't visible to me. Now things make more sense :D

Comment: Yes, your right little fast in combining the lamda there.

Comment: This will now at least compile, but the question remains: Why do you believe this suggestion is beneficial? You've basically told @Joel to convert his lambda expressions into anonymous classes, but the two versions of the code are functionally equivalent. In other words, this shouldn't make any difference to the logic of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing instance variables in your getNextRoundFromServer() method and you're now calling the method from within a new (anonymous) Runnable instance, So your references to "this" may not resolve to where you think they're resolving.

Perhaps pass in a reference to the original instance?

```
private void getNextRoundFromServer(YourObjectClass instance) throws IOException{
    try{
        if(!instance.connected) return;
        instance.dos.writeByte(2);
        instance.dos.flush(); // Send data
        instance.grid = (Grid) instance.ois.readObject(); //i have checked, i do recieve this object
        setMainPane(render.render(instance.grid)); //this renders the view
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


continuousPlayButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    try {
        final instanceRef = getReferenceToYourOriginalInstance();  
        Runnable scheduledRound = () -> {
            try {
                getNextRoundFromServer( instanceRef );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(scheduledRound, 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```